# Login with youtube API and save info for later use like to upload vidoes for my customer etc

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

Below is the code sample. However I am not able to save information for the logged in user and later used by the system admin to upload videos for him using API.

**Now currently each time user has to login and authenticate from Google to get access token to upload Vidoes etc. I want a way to register once then information I can use later any time and user do not need again to authenticate from google to get session data/token.**

$client->$client->getAccessToken() token gives me

> {"access_token":"XXXXXXXXX","token_type":"Bearer", "expires_in":3600,
>   "refresh_token":"XXXXXXX", "created":000000}

I want to store/save some information that can be used later by some one else for the user if user is logged in or off.

```
 <?php

    // Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
    set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/directory/to/google/api/');
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
    session_start();

    /*
     * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
     * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
     * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
     * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
     * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
     */
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
    $REDIRECT = 'http://localhost/oauth2callback.php';
    $APPNAME = "XXXXXXXXX";


    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
    $client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT);
    $client->setApplicationName($APPNAME);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');


    // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
            die('The session state did not match.');
        }

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        echo '<code>' . $_SESSION['token'] . '</code>';
    }

    // Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        try {
            // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
            // currently authenticated user's channel.
            $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
                'mine' => 'true',
            ));

            $htmlBody = '';
            foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
                // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
                // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
                // to retrieve that list.
                $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

                $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
                    'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
                    'maxResults' => 50
                ));

                $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
                foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
                    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
                        $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
                }
                $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
            }
        } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
                htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
                htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        }

        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
        $state = mt_rand();
        $client->setState($state);
        $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $htmlBody = <<<END
      <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
      <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorise access</a> before proceeding.<p>
    END;
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Uploads</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php echo $htmlBody?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: save the refresh_token in the response and use it to gain access to their account next time.

Comment: But it is automatically expired after an hour or so and also stores in browser, I want to save info permanently and used by the admin to manage his account

Comment: the access token expires after 1 hour.  The refresh token will not expire until the user removes your access. You use the refresh token to request a new access token when the one you are using has expired.    Save the refresh token and request a new access token when your admin need to manage his account

Answer (score 3):

To implement this , every time a new user login to your application ,save the `refresh Token` in some database . Now , every time the already authenticated user logs in , look for the user with the same refresh token . If matched , then use that `refresh token` to generate access tokens for the user . Refresh tokens never expire , so you can rely on them to authenticate the already registered users . hope this helps you !! Have a look at this statement right from the documentation

> Save refresh tokens in secure long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. Limits apply to the number of refresh tokens that are issued per client-user combination, and per user across all clients, and these limits are different. If your application requests enough refresh tokens to go over one of the limits, older refresh tokens stop working.

Comment: Hi, above code now returns(very strange) {"access_token":"XXXXX","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"id_token":"XXXXXXXXXX","created":1467008014}

There is no refresh token

Comment: are you using access=offline in your request in the url ?

Comment: Soory my mistake, my database column length was small which was unable to store refresh token, so why it was omitted:)

Comment: Good that you helped your self :) kudos !!

Comment: Quite late but to add: Refresh token is not identical on every new youtube login regardless of whether the user already authorized the app or not; Which means there can't be identical refresh token at least for what I tested. (Using Server flow)